# Automatic scrolling on touchpad

Tags: lubuntu, scrolling

I just installed Lubuntu for the first time and am really pleased about the way it looks and feels. Everything works as it shoud except one thing.

When I use the touchpad of my laptop, with 1 finger, and not near the scrollbar. It still scrolls.. sometimes. Most of the time it's ok but sometimes it just scrolls up or down. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to turn the touch-pad off?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I suspect your touchpad is configured for two finger scrolling and that "most of the time" you are accidentally touching your touchpad with two fingers.  If you do this all of the time it will work that way all of the time.